# Make new dataframes based on splitting a big dataframe's column values

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I am trying to split a very big dataframe into multiple dataframes where column value starts with "-----..." and until I reach "-----..."

I have a big dataframe (made by reading a text file and later prepared into a df) containing more than 1.9m rows,

```
a = c("pass-100.0","pass-100.0","pass-100.0","pass-100.0","pass-100.0","----------------------- NET XI50|XI1|XI15|net311","X","garbage","pass-100.0","pass-100.0","pass-100.0","pass-100.0","pass-100.0","----------------------- NET XI50|XI1|XI15|net311","Y","garbage","pass-100.0","pass-100.0","pass-100.0","pass-100.0","pass-100.0")
b = c("r321_1096","r321_1098","r321_1097","r321_1095","r321_1093","-------------------------------","Z","garbage","r321_1096","r321_1098","r321_1097","r321_1095","r321_1093","-------------------------------","P","garbage","r321_1096","r321_1098","r321_1097","r321_1095","r321_1093")
c = c("0.04","0.04","-1","0.04","-1","","Q","garbage","0.04","0.04","-1","0.04","-1","","R","garbage","0.04","0.04","-1","0.04","-1")
d = c("0.32","0.32","0","0.32","0","","S","garbage","0.32","0.32","0","0.32","0","","T","garbage","0.32","0.32","0","0.32","0")
df = data.frame(a, b, c, d)
```

I want to split the df into smaller dataframes where column 'a' starts with "----------------------- NET XI50|XI1|XI15|net311" and the dataframe ends when it encounters "----------------------- NET XI50|XI1|XI15|net311" for the second time.

I want to keep the column names as a, b and c for all the new dataframes and remove the row containing "garbage" values in the smaller dataframes. Later, I plan on doing some common calculations on these dataframes. But I cant think of a way to split the big dataframe into usable ones. Any idea how I should proceed?

[image]

Comment: It would probably be the easiest to do it before you create the data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest doing something like this:

```r
df |> 
  mutate(group = cumsum(a |> str_starts("---"))) |> 
  nest(data = -group) |> 
  rowwise(group) |> 
  summarise(
    data = list(
      if (group == 0) data else slice_tail(data, n = -3)
    )
  )

#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   group data            
#>   <int> <list>          
#> 1     0 <tibble [5 × 4]>
#> 2     1 <tibble [5 × 4]>
#> 3     2 <tibble [5 × 4]>
```

---

**Explanation:** First, we create a column that indicates when each new chunk starts

```r
df |> 
  mutate(
    group = cumsum(a |> str_starts("----"))
  ) 
#> # A tibble: 21 × 5
#>    a                                                b          c     d     group
#>    <chr>                                            <chr>      <chr> <chr> <int>
#>  1 pass-100.0                                       r321_1096  "0.0… "0.3…     0
#>  2 pass-100.0                                       r321_1098  "0.0… "0.3…     0
#>  3 pass-100.0                                       r321_1097  "-1"  "0"       0
#>  4 pass-100.0                                       r321_1095  "0.0… "0.3…     0
#>  5 pass-100.0                                       r321_1093  "-1"  "0"       0
#>  6 ----------------------- NET XI50|XI1|XI15|net311 ---------… ""    ""        1
#>  7 X                                                Z          "Q"   "S"       1
#>  8 garbage                                          garbage    "gar… "gar…     1
#>  9 pass-100.0                                       r321_1096  "0.0… "0.3…     1
#> 10 pass-100.0                                       r321_1098  "0.0… "0.3…     1
#> # … with 11 more rows
```

and now you could nest the groups into separate dataframes

```r
df |> 
  mutate(
    group = cumsum(a |> str_starts("----"))
  ) |> 
  nest(data = -group)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   group data            
#>   <int> <list>          
#> 1     0 <tibble [5 × 4]>
#> 2     1 <tibble [8 × 4]>
#> 3     2 <tibble [8 × 4]>
```

which then can be processed using a combination of rowwise and summarise

```r
df |> 
  mutate(
    group = cumsum(a |> str_starts("----"))
  ) |> 
  nest(data = -group) |> 
  rowwise(group) |> 
  summarise(
    data = list(
      if (group == 0) data else slice_tail(data, n = -3)
    )
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   group data            
#>   <int> <list>          
#> 1     0 <tibble [5 × 4]>
#> 2     1 <tibble [5 × 4]>
#> 3     2 <tibble [5 × 4]>
```

Comment: How would I also store the names eg, "NET XI50|XI1|XI15|net311" in one of the new columns? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `split` function to do this.  It relies on making a factor corresponding to each group, which you can get using `cumsum` to count the number of rows that have matched to `----` in column A.  The result is a list of data frames (I've also filtered out the 'garbage' row):

```
split(df[df$a!="garbage",] , cumsum(grepl("----",df[df$a!="garbage","a"])))


$`0`
           a         b    c    d
1 pass-100.0 r321_1096 0.04 0.32
2 pass-100.0 r321_1098 0.04 0.32
3 pass-100.0 r321_1097   -1    0
4 pass-100.0 r321_1095 0.04 0.32
5 pass-100.0 r321_1093   -1    0

$`1`
                                                  a                               b    c    d
6  ----------------------- NET XI50|XI1|XI15|net311 -------------------------------          
7                                                 X                               Z    Q    S
9                                        pass-100.0                       r321_1096 0.04 0.32
10                                       pass-100.0                       r321_1098 0.04 0.32
11                                       pass-100.0                       r321_1097   -1    0
12                                       pass-100.0                       r321_1095 0.04 0.32
13                                       pass-100.0                       r321_1093   -1    0

$`2`
                                                  a                               b    c    d
14 ----------------------- NET XI50|XI1|XI15|net311 -------------------------------          
15                                                Y                               P    R    T
17                                       pass-100.0                       r321_1096 0.04 0.32
18                                       pass-100.0                       r321_1098 0.04 0.32
19                                       pass-100.0                       r321_1097   -1    0
20                                       pass-100.0                       r321_1095 0.04 0.32
21                                       pass-100.0                       r321_1093   -1    0
```

Answer (score 1):

Or a `dplyr` equivalent using (the experimental, but handy) `group_split`.

I would, however, recommend that you do this on the txt before you create the data frames: It's (probably) easier, safer, and faster for 1.9m rows.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df |>
  group_by(group = cumsum(str_detect(a,
                                     fixed("----------------------- NET XI50|XI1|XI15|net311")))) |> # Fixed is faster but approximate
  filter(between(row_number(), 4, n()) & group > 0 | group == 0) |>
  group_split(.keep = FALSE)
```

Output:

```r
[[1]]
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  a          b         c     d    
  <chr>      <chr>     <chr> <chr>
1 pass-100.0 r321_1096 0.04  0.32 
2 pass-100.0 r321_1098 0.04  0.32 
3 pass-100.0 r321_1097 -1    0    
4 pass-100.0 r321_1095 0.04  0.32 
5 pass-100.0 r321_1093 -1    0    

[[2]]
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  a          b         c     d    
  <chr>      <chr>     <chr> <chr>
1 pass-100.0 r321_1096 0.04  0.32 
2 pass-100.0 r321_1098 0.04  0.32 
3 pass-100.0 r321_1097 -1    0    
4 pass-100.0 r321_1095 0.04  0.32 
5 pass-100.0 r321_1093 -1    0    

[[3]]
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  a          b         c     d    
  <chr>      <chr>     <chr> <chr>
1 pass-100.0 r321_1096 0.04  0.32 
2 pass-100.0 r321_1098 0.04  0.32 
3 pass-100.0 r321_1097 -1    0    
4 pass-100.0 r321_1095 0.04  0.32 
5 pass-100.0 r321_1093 -1    0
```